# select box issue on OSX

Tags: html, css

in my audio streaming application (displayed all in a browser) users can use a HTML select box in order to adjust a network buffer size from 1 to 99.

The background of the box can change from green to red or vice versa depending on the actual streaming condition (the more red the user will typically adjust higher values).

In that context I have a slight problem on OSX (not on Windows):

When the user intends to pick a new buffer value but before actually clicking the mouse the backgrund of the select box changes then the position of the select box flips back to the original value.

In fact I already implemented a mouseClick / mouseLeave - event but the problem is that after the click on the element, hovering over the select-options is already interpreted as mouseLeave, which makes this solution obsolete.

Does anyone have a better idea ?

Thanks in advance,
best

Alex

Comment: it's hard to understand ... can You add some screenshots ...

Comment: Sure - but I think a video screen capture makes even more sense - please find it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9s5ywl12mt0w8km/capture.mov?dl=0

Comment: try to remove jQuery and make it by CSS only ... :active, :focus, :hover ... it looks like script set hover action but then it's overwritten ... also You use some interval to check state of select box ? I can only say that this is not OS X problem ... I also make everything on OS X and never seen something like this. You must create bad logic.